# Website is accessible from phone but not from computer on the same network

Tags: networking, router

Computer is a laptop running Windows 10 connected to ethernet and WiFi.
Phone is on Android connected to WiFi.
Router is Technicolor EPC3928AD DOCSIS 3.0 Wireless Gateway.

The website I've been trying to access is github.com. So far I've only noticed the issue on github and the proxy websites that I've been trying to use to open github.

The error I get is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge). **But** I can ping github.com without any issues. I can also access github.com on phone **most** of the time.

Windows Network Diagnostics says "resource (github.com) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts."

Something weird that I have noticed is that randomly, the computer disconnects from ethernet and connects to Wifi. During this time even the phone cannot access github.com (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT). But during this the error in the browser is (ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE). This lasts for about 10 seconds at a time.

What I've tried so far:

- Network reset on Windows.
- Restarting router and computer multiple times.
- Turning off both Windows and router firewalls.
- `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- `netsh advfirewall reset`
- `ipconfig /flushdns`
- `ipconfig /registerdns`
- `route /f`

Answer (score 0):

Some people disable IPv6, or their operating system or device (e.g. router) has IPv6 disabled by default. Is IPv6 support enabled for your connection? If not, edit your network connection (check router as well) in order to enable IPv6 support. A common **IPv6 enabled** setting for a network connection is this:

```
Automatic, DHCP only
```

[image: Enable IPv6 support in "Automatic, DHCP only" mode]

After enabling IPv6, don't forget to disable your connection and then enable it again, so when you use it to connect to the network the new configuration is loaded. If such change doesn't seem to work, either restart the networking daemon/service or reboot the computer.

Comment: IPv6 is not a security risk, so disabling it doesn't improve security. It's generally disabled because it's not used in the network, and most of today's SoHo routers don't have IPv6 capabilities, so enabling it makes little sense.

Comment: @Peregrino69 My concerns with IPv6 began after I read https://www.esecurityplanet.com/networks/ipv6-security-risks. Networking isn't my strong suit, though. Anyway: after many unsuccessful attempts to load github.com in my Desktop's browser, I noticed that my IPv6-enabled smartphone could load that, then I suspected that github.com could be hosting content at an IPv6 location, decided to enable IPv6 and it indeed solved the issue. I hope my answer helps other people experiencing the same issue. Last but not least: thanks for taking the time to comment here, I need to read more about IPv6.

Comment: Notice it's a decade old article - that's a very long time in computing :-) By far most of the points made concern how then-current tools and technologies were coping with IPv6. It's not surprising that tech sites like Github would be among the first adopters of IPv6. At this time they all support both. But in practice the relevance of your client configuration stops at your router - have a peek, I'm betting the WAN page shows only IPv4 address. The most likely reason why your PC didn't reach github.com is a simple DNS failure; the IPv4 DNS server wasn't able to resolve github.com to an IP.

Comment: Check Wikipedia's article on [IPv6 deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_deployment). That gives a pretty accurate overview of the current status. IPv6 is just another addressing method, the data transfer protocols are still good ole TCP and UDP used with IPv4.

Comment: @Peregrino69 While IPv6 support was set as `disabled` in my network connection, I tried several (private and public) DNS servers but none worked. Then I enabled IPv6 and restarted the networking daemon (I'm on Linux, so I ran `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`). Immediately after doing this and having my WLAN connection up again, the Github page loaded normally with both private and public DNS servers. Then I disabled IPv6 again and restarted the networking daemon, and then I couldn't access github.com anymore. I mean: weird as it seems, everything points at IPv6 as the culprit.

Comment: Not saying you're not correct, just what's the most common reason behind failures like that :-) A DNS failure doesn't even mean the DNS server is failing, just that something in the DNS process fails. Can't go anywhere deeper than general level without detailed info on the setup as a whole. Not really stuff for a SE community :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 I know, don't worry, I can see that you're providing info with the best intentions and I appreciate it, seriously. I forgot to mention: my 2 laptops and my smartphone are connected to the same wi-fi network from the same Home Gateway Unit, with the same DNS servers' configuration (I tested with my ISP's DNS, Google's DNS etc.), yet only my IPv6-enabled smartphone loaded the Github page while both IPv6-disabled laptops didn't, then I enabled the smartphone's mobile/4G+ AP (access point) mode and then both IPv6-disabled laptops connected to the AP and successfully loaded github.com.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I checked the Wikipedia article. I'm in Brazil and I'm surprised to read there that Brazil currently has 40.9% IPv6 adoption (it actually mentions 38.4%, but I checked the primary source and it's currently 40.9%). In the U.S. it's 43.78%. The total number of possible IPv6 addresses is 4.35E28 times the world's population: that's a lot of addresses, we're never going to *fill* this. Nice.

Comment: You got it mate :-D But to quote the ancient wisdom, `Never say never` ;-) It'll take some time, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start by choosing either Ethernet or Wi-Fi.

In default settings your router is providing IP addresses in both networks in the same IP range, which means your system can get 2 separate IP addresses (IP interfaces) into the same subnet. As an example the router's DHCP server gives your LAN interface IP `192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0` and your Wi-Fi interface `192.168.1.11 255.255.255.0`.

Having 2 IP interfaces into the same subnet is a surefire way to invite trouble, unless you use some link aggregation method such as NIC teaming or a redundancy method such as configuring primary /standup adapters.

NIC teaming requires that the receiving end understands aggregation, not a common feature in a SoHo internet router. Primary / standup is a feature of the host alone, but makes little sense. If you use only the Ethernet connection, it's very unlikely to fail completely in the way that would actually require a backup adapter. Wi-Fi connection may experience drops due to signal loss, which is most of the time due to just interference and can be fixed by switching the AP to another channel.